# Why does Math.Round() change MidpointRounding after decimal 1100

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone explain to me why the below code outputs 1100 in both cases?

```
decimal toEven = 1100.5m;
decimal awayFromZero = 1099.5m;

Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(toEven)); // output 1100
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(awayFromZero)); // output 1100
```

It looks like that Math.Round() changes MidpointRounding strategy after the number 1100. If you use Math.Round() on decimals under 1100 with a .5 decimal Math.Round() uses the AwayFromZero MidpointRounding by default. But if you use decimals over 1100 Math.Round() will use the ToEven MidpointRound by default. Why?

I know i can set the MidpointRounding my self to fix the problem. I'm just curious why Math.Round() works like this.

Comment: How did you find `1100`? It always rounds to the even number by default.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm just curious why Math.Round() works like this.

Because that's the way it's designed [and documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk(v=vs.110).aspx) to behave:

> If the fractional component of *d* is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, the even number is returned.

The behaviour doesn't change around 1100 either, `Math.Round(1097.5m)` and `Math.Round(1098.5m)` both return 1098 for example.

Comment: I can see that i misunderstood the behavior of the to even term. Thanks for clarifying.